# Swiper.js control two instances with different option loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I try to make a slider with thumb like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7wa109z2/)

But i want my slider is `loop=true` and my thumb is `loop=false`.
Here is my setting

```
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      loop: true
});
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true
});
galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
```

But everything not working. my slider and my thumb not do the same item. How to do that thank.

Comment: can you add your html too?

Comment: @yash i have example with link in https://jsfiddle.net/7wa109z2/

Answer (score 8):

One way of doing this is to remove the slide's association and slide them manually using [swiper events](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events)

```
galleryTop.on('slideChangeTransitionEnd', function() {
  let index_currentSlide = galleryTop.realIndex;
  let currentSlide = galleryTop.slides[index_currentSlide]
  galleryThumbs.slideTo(index_currentSlide, 1000, false);
});

galleryThumbs.on('slideChangeTransitionEnd', function() {
  let index_currentSlide = galleryThumbs.realIndex;
  let currentSlide = galleryThumbs.slides[index_currentSlide]
  galleryTop.slideTo(index_currentSlide, 1000, false);
});
```

Here's a working example below where I added the code above and removed the 2 controller associations.

```js
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  loopedSlides: 5,
  loop: true
});
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  loopedSlides: 5
});

galleryTop.on('slideChangeTransitionEnd', function() {
  let index_currentSlide = galleryTop.realIndex;
  let currentSlide = galleryTop.slides[index_currentSlide]
  galleryThumbs.slideTo(index_currentSlide, 1000, false);
});

galleryThumbs.on('slideChangeTransitionEnd', function() {
  let index_currentSlide = galleryThumbs.realIndex;
  let currentSlide = galleryThumbs.slides[index_currentSlide]
  galleryTop.slideTo(index_currentSlide, 1000, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.swiper-slide-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-top {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-thumbs {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-WNLxfP/8cVYL9sj8Jnp6et0BkubLP31jhTG9vhL/F5uEZmg5wEzKoXp1kJslzPQWwPT1eyMiSxlKCgzHLOTOTQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.4/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.0.4/swiper-bundle.css" />

<body>
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-container">Slide 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: but it's not dragging life-time ?

Comment: @DeLe I forgot to add the event on the bottom thumbs, I added a link to the swiper events for your reference as well. But the live drag is not available using events.

Comment: that seem's bug on library and just add to https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3730 but no help

Comment: @DeLe it is a bug, you can't combine a `loop: true` with a `loop: false` in the thumb, that's why I offered another way of doing it. It's not perfect, but it's an alternative.